# Power-Automate: Copy and Archive files

Tags: power-automate

I have a document that needs to be updated every 2 weeks for a particular meeting. I have to share the document so everyone can make the updates before the meeting

Ideally, I'd like to fully automate this process as I often forget to do it!
So, every 2 weeks I need to send a mail with the most recent file shared as a link to ask for the updates.
After the meeting, I want to copy that doc with the date for the next meeting (i.e. today + two weeks) and then archive the old file.
And then, when the mail sends again, it will link to the new file

For example:

- Meeting is on Monday 21st Nov
- Mail sends automatically on the Tuesday before (i.e. the 15th Nov) with a link to the file named MeetingFile_21Nov22
- On the 21st, after the meeting, MeetingFile_21Nov22 is copied and renamed MeetingFile_5Dec22, and MeetingFile_21Nov22 is archived into a separate folder
- Mail sends automatically on the Tuesday before (i.e. the 29th Nov) with a link to the file named MeetingFile_6Dec22

I've tried the advice in this threatd (https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Archive-Old-file-and-Create-New/m-p/1693329) but I can't get the variables right to pick up the correct files, rename them, and then send the right mail!

I find that when I need to rename the file, I have to tell the flow the current file name rather than being able to reference something like "latest file". And then once the name is changed, all my other references break.

Hoping you guys can assist :)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you attempted anything at all?  It's typically a prerequisite to asking a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi @Skin yes I tried a couple of things but should have been more specific! I posted in the power automate community and received these responses - https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Archive-Old-file-and-Create-New/m-p/1693329

Essentially combining Copy File, Get File and Send email - but I couldn't work out how to reference the copied file without using the explicit file name, which would change every 2 weeks. I also couldn't get the Send email to work without referencing the specific file name

Comment: Have you considered breaking this up into more than 1 flow?  For example, creating the email reminder flow, then creating another one to archive?